# Why dynamic select box json value not working?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

```
<select id="CFG_USERS_DFTLEVEL" name="CFG_USERS_DFTLEVEL"  ng-options="obj.CFG_ORGLEVEL_ID as obj.CFG_ORGLEVEL_CODE for obj in items"  ng-model="formData.CFG_USERS_DFTLEVEL">
<option value="">Select Default Org Level</option></select>

HTML Code above
```

Static value working dood..But dynamic Json value not working

**data response output:**

```
{"orglevel":[{"CFG_ORGLEVEL_ID":"1","CFG_ORGLEVEL_CODE":"AEB"},{"CFG_ORGLEVEL_ID":"2","CFG_ORGLEVEL_CODE"
:"MTL"},{"CFG_ORGLEVEL_ID":"3","CFG_ORGLEVEL_CODE":"TOR"}]}
```

Controller code here:

```
$http.post('test/test.php',userdata).success(function(data) {


    var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data['orglevel']);

/* static value work fine*/

//$scope.items = [{ "CFG_ORGLEVEL_ID": 1, "CFG_ORGLEVEL_CODE": "AEB" }, { "CFG_ORGLEVEL_ID": 2, "CFG_ORGLEVEL_CODE": "MTL" }, { "CFG_ORGLEVEL_ID": 2, "CFG_ORGLEVEL_CODE": "TOR" }];

$scope.items = jsondata ; //not working

});
```

Comment: Try use `JSON.parse()` if you want it as an array

Comment: Thank you so much...It working fine...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you stringify-ing the response ?

`data` should already be a javascript object.

Just do `$scope.items = data.orglevel;`